# Behavior of Thread B spawned inside Thread A when Thread A dies

Tags: java, multithreading

I want execute Thread when main Thread release resources.

I have main Thread

```
Thread mainThread = new Thread(() -> {
    //do things
    doAction();
    //do other things
});
```

and method `doAction()` looks like

```
public void doAction(){
   Thread insideThread = new Thread(() -> {
      //do something
   });

   insideThread.start();
}
```

Now it looks that the `insideThread` is executed while `mainThread` is running.

What happens to `insideThread` when `mainThread` dies or is released?

I want start `insideThread`  at the moment when `mainThread` dies or released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution: change `doAction()` to **return** that thread it is creating; so that the **calling** code can call *start()* on that Thread; like this:

```
public Thread doAction(){
  Thread insideThread = new Thread(() -> {
    //do something
  });

  return insideThread;
}
```

Of course, you would then rename that method to something like *prepareAction()* to indicate that it doesn't "do" things itself.

Edit: this is **one** option to implement your requirement; but the core thing is: no matter if that method returns a value; or (for example) sets some field - the point is: if you want to **control** a thread T from within another thread M, than M needs a reference to that T. There is no magic here, any object can only "manage" other objects that are *somehow* known to it!

Comment: I do like this answer because the code could predate Tasks, but I would suggest adding an async/await and Tasks example as well since it's the more modern approach to said thing.

Comment: @RagingCain Thank you; sounds like a good idea; but not sure if I get there today.Feel free to edit and improve my answer. Now I am wondering if mentioning that I am a grateful upvoter would look like attempted bribery ;-)